# Track database name in anemometer queries

Tags: mysql, performance, anemometer, query-performance

Hello i have installed anemometer on our server in order to see the queries that need optimization.

From the website hosted a few have a wordpress blog on them so it is hard to guess witch one is affecting the most in the query bellow:

```
select  wp_posts.*
    from  wp_posts
    inner join  wp_postmeta on ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    where  ?=?
      and  ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = ?
               and  cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value as char) = ? ) 
           )
      and  wp_posts.post_type = ?
      and  ((wp_posts.post_status = ?))
    group by  wp_posts.id
    order by  wp_posts.post_date desc
```

Is there a way to track the database as well in anemometer?

Comment: Why do you need `CAST()`?  What is `?=?`?  Which table(s) might that reference?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: The query is from a wordpress blog. So the query is not build by me :)

Comment: Any idea what will be substituted there?  It could make a big difference in optimizing the query.

Answer (score 0):

(Until I get answers to my comment, here is all I can suggest...)

<strike>1. `LEFT` and the two tests on `wp_postmeta` have no impact on the outcome; get rid of them.</strike>

2. Get rid of `wp_postmeta` all together.  And get rid of the `GROUP BY`, which was probably a byproduct of the `JOIN`.
3. `INDEX(post_type, post_status, post_date)`

That leaves you with just

```
select  *
    from  wp_posts
    where  post_type = ?
      and  post_status = ?
    order by  post_date desc
```

Does that give you the right answer?

Comment: Since this is a wordpress installation i cannot go alter the code and queries. I was interested to find out to which blog has the slow queries. Since all of them have the same database structure and queries i could do that through the database name. This is my question, how can i track the database name as well as the query

Comment: Turn on the slowlog, lower long_query_time, and wait for something to show up in the slowlog.

Comment: @RickJames where did you see `LEFT` in the query?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ -- I do make mistakes.  :(

Comment: @no worries. I only looked at this after another `[anemometer]` question appeared (and was curious what this anemometer is). Didn't realize that this one was a year old, until I sent you the message.

Comment: I don't know what SQL anemometer does.  I guess this is the answer:  https://github.com/box/Anemometer and https://github.com/box/Anemometer/wiki .